# unable to resolve "react-native-gesture-handler" from "node_modules/@react-navigation/native/src/Scrollables.js"

Tags: react-native, expo, node-modules, npm-install

I am trying to run on Android simulator, and Expo showed like:

> unable to resolve "react-native-gesture-handler" from "node_modules/@react-navigation/native/src/Scrollables.js"

I did the below 2 things according to https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/getting-started.html:

> npm install react-navigation
>
> expo install react-native-gesture-handler react-native-reanimated react-native-screens react-native-safe-area-context @react-native-community/masked-view

And my package.json is like this below.

```
{
  "main": "node_modules/expo/AppEntry.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "expo start",
    "android": "expo start --android",
    "ios": "expo start --ios",
    "web": "expo start --web",
    "eject": "expo eject"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@react-native-community/masked-view": "0.1.5",
    "expo": "~36.0.0",
    "firebase": "^7.8.0",
    "react": "~16.9.0",
    "react-dom": "~16.9.0",
    "react-native": "https://github.com/expo/react-native/archive/sdk-36.0.0.tar.gz",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "~1.5.0",
    "react-native-reanimated": "~1.4.0",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "0.6.0",
    "react-native-screens": "2.0.0-alpha.12",
    "react-native-web": "~0.11.7",
    "react-navigation": "^4.1.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-preset-expo": "~8.0.0",
    "@babel/core": "^7.0.0"
  },
  "private": true
}
```

Please advise how to solve this issue. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

use

```
npm i react-native-gesture-handler
```

Answer (score 1):

Follow these commands:
`npm install jetifier`
Then run:
`npx jetifier`